# Will Private URL be accepted for Chromecast Device Registration?

Tags: device, registration, whitelist, google-cast, chromecast

Chromecast Device Whitelist Request, First Time Registration states that

> It is ok for your receiver to be on an internal (NAT'd) IP address,
>   but not `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` as that will resolve to 
>   the Chromecast device itself and will not work.

So is it fine, If I provide private URL for Whitelisting my device and URL? I provided following URL

```
http://192.168.0.1/rdx/englishfree.html
```

Above is the local IP of my machine, the IP is provided by the router internally. So is this URL acceptable by Google ? Google cannot check this URL, since it is behind my router.

I have not received any mail from google yet from past 2 days (for rejection or acceptance)

Please advice.

Comment: 192.168.0.1 is a perfectly valid address. We are currently running the WL process every 3-4 days, so it should happen shortly.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel Thanks! Yesterday I got mail from google having my device whitelisted and application ID (though I am yet to use the same) I request you to put your comments in answer so that I can accept the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

192.168.0.1 is a perfectly valid address. We are currently running the WL process every 3-4 days, so it should happen shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Google have accepted a very similar URL from me (`http://192.168.1.5/chromecast`) and it works just fine for testing the app

The registration website would not accept the internal private DNS entry I have for it (http://tiefighter.loc/chromecast) but took the IP address just fine. (This makes sense give the other answer suggests the chromecast is using Googles DNS servers rather than the one handed out by the local DHCP server)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a private address since it won't work. Chromecast device uses Google's DNS and a local private address will not be recognized outside of your network, hence when chromecast tries to download your receiver, it fails.

Comment: but then what does google mean by saying "It is ok for your receiver to be on an internal (NAT'd) IP address, but not http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 as that will resolve to the Chromecast device itself and will not work."?

Comment: To be clear, if you use ip address directly, then it won't need to go to a DNS server to resolve that so it will find your server on your local network, but if you use a name, then it will contact Google's DNS to resolve the name. So if "mydomain.com" is set to point to my local server within my local DNS of my router, that is not going to work since name resolution happens using Google's DNS server and not your routers, but if 192.168.0.1 points to your server directly, it is fine.